# powershell echo and function parameters

Tags: powershell

I've discovered some weird behaviour with echo and function parameters - in this example:

```
function a
{
    $one = "1"
    echo "display some text"
    return @{one = $one}
}

function b
{
    param ($one)
    echo $one
}

$returnedHash = a
echo $returnedHash
b @returnedHash
```

the output is:

```
display some text

Name                           Value                                  
----                           -----                                       
one                            1                                      
display some text
```

$one in function b is wrong, as long as you use echo in function a. (using Write-Host gets expected results)

So what am I not understanding here? this is not a scoping issue - it appears to be something to do with echo using pipelines, and possibly splatting?

Comment: Try `a|Get-Member` and `$returnehash|Get-Member` You'll see the output is an array consisting of a string **and** a hashtable. The function will return **any** output generated inside, not just what follows return.

Comment: thanks, you were absolutely correct!